# Tensorflow and keras in R

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to develop a neural network model in R, and I need keras and tensorflow for that, but it seems quite difficult to actually get those libraries in R. What I currently have tried is:

- downloaded python
- downloaded anaconda
- ran `install_keras()` and `install_tensorflow()` in RStudio

When I run both `keras::install_keras()` and `tensorflow::install_tensorflow()`, I get the following error:

> Error in virtualenv_install(envname = envname, packages = packages, ignore_installed = pip_ignore_installed,  : 'r-tensorflow' exists but is not a virtual environment

And when I run `neural_network = keras_model_sequential() %>% layer_dense(units = 50, activation = "relu", input_shape = ncol(x)) %>% layer_dropout(rate = 0.4) %>% layer_dense(units = 1)`, I get

> `Error: Valid installation of TensorFlow not found.

Python environments searched for 'tensorflow' package:
C:\Users\alex\anaconda3\python.exe

Python exception encountered:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\reticulate\python\rpytools\loader.py", line 119, in _find_and_load_hook
return _run_hook(name, _hook)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\reticulate\python\rpytools\loader.py", line 93, in _run_hook
module = hook()
^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\reticulate\python\rpytools\loader.py", line 117, in _hook
return *find_and_load(name, import*)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

You can install TensorFlow using the install_tensorflow() function.

Could someone help me please?

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'. Do you have tensorflow installed using pip install.

Comment: @Golem thats 'pip install tensorflow' in a command prompt right? i think so, yes

Comment: I have no experience. But you can checkout [Tensorflow R documentation](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/install/).

Comment: @LMaxime im familiar with that, it doesnt provide what i need

Comment: Are you using the same python interpreter in R? if not you will experience this issue.  Better install tensorflow from R to ensure it is installed in the right path. ie in you rstudio console run`reticulate::repl_python()` this will start python Ipython kernel in the console. run `!pip install tensorflow`. Then run `exit` to go back to R interpreter, then do `install.packages('tensorflow')`.

Comment: @Onyambu i tried your instructions, but it says 'valid installation of tensorflow not found' again

Comment: i think it might have something to do with not being able to connect all the things together properly. because i think i have a lot of things installed: python, anaconda, keras, tensorflow. but i think rstudio might have trouble connecting all the things together, but i could be wrong

Comment: You already asked the exact same question yesterday, we do not allow duplicate questions, this is not a forum.